# Неожиданный результат применения стиля для EditText

Tags: android, android-customview

Решил я в программе заменить рисунки png на vector. Все получилось хорошо. Проверял на многих смартфонах разных версий Android. Но недавно один из пользователей прислал скриншот в котором вид EditText оказался не таким как планировалось. Хотя раньше у него же, но с png было все хорошо. В чем моя ошибка при использовании vector?

keyboard.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="24dp" android:width="24dp" android:viewportWidth="24" android:viewportHeight="24">
```

edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <stroke 
                    android:width="1dp" 
                    android:color="@color/actionbar_background" />
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/actionbar_text_color" />
                <padding
                    android:left="2dp" 
                    android:top="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/keyboard"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            />
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

style для EditText

```
<style name="edittext" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:ems">10</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">text|textMultiLine</item>
</style>
```

Как предполагалось быть
[image: Как предполагалось быть]
Как стало

[image: Как стало]

Comment: Вроде, у `item` есть возможность размер задать. Может помочь. А вообще - лучше не пытаться с этим воевать и иконку через `compaundDrawable` сделать, а рамку - во вмещающем контенере. Так точно проблем нигде никаких не будет.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, да есть такая возможность для API>=23. Сделал так, но не проверил еще...

Comment: ЮрийСПб, а что это за "иконку через compaundDrawable сделать, а рамку - во вмещающем контенере" - где-нибудь пример есть?

Comment: Просто оберните EditText в FrameLayout, у коего будет фон с рамкой. У EditText иконку с клавиатурой укажите через аттрибут `android:drawableStart="@drawable/keyboard"`

Comment: ЮрийСПб, android:drawableStart только для API 17, а у меня минимальный 14...

Comment: Попробуйте тогда `android:drawableLeft`

Comment: ЮрийСПб, спасибо, но он просто по середине. Как его прижать сверху/слева например?

Comment: Это невозможно. Используйте вариант с контейнером

Comment: ЮрийСПб, да спасибо. Пожалуй это единственный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо ЮрийСПб
Все получилось. Конечно пришлось все перековырять, но работает везде одинаково.

```
<RelativeLayout
style="@style/edittext_wrapper">
<ImageView
    style="@style/edittext_image"/>
<EditText></EditText></RelativeLayout>
```

Без подробностей, но суть такая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]